# Proving that the measure of a right angle is $90^\circ$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am stumped on the following question:

> Prove that the measure of a right angle is $90^\circ$.

I so far have tried extending the lines making the angles but I can't get anything.  I am not sure what kind of theorems to use.

I would appreciate it if someone could give me a hint about what theorems to use or where to start.

Some of the theorems that I am allowed to use are:

- The measure of each linear angle is $180^\circ$.
- Congruent angles have the same measure.
- Angle smaller than and number smaller than coincide
- Any theorems on the transitivity of parallel lines.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your definition of a right angle?

Comment: My definition of a right angles is 90 degrees, but I have to prove that its measure is 90.

Comment: I think you have to define the right angle without degrees and you have to define how to measure angles. Otherwise I can say your current definition is wrong as the measure of right angle is $\pi/2.$

Comment: Are you allowed to use that the measure of a straight angle is 180? What theorems/properties/definition of "measure of an angle" are you allowed to use?

Comment: Can you give more context ?

Comment: @GerryMyerson  Yes I am allowed to use that the measure of a straight angle is 180.  Why? Does that help?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo  See the edit

Comment: Do you have a way to relate straight angles to right angles? a way to show that if you have a right angle and you extend one of the sides past the intersection, you get a straight angle as the sum of two right angles?

Comment: Are you proving a particular theorem ?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo No, but my previous definition was wrong.  The definition given is a right angle is an angle that is supplementary to itself

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks I think I may have solved my own question

Comment: I'd encourage you to write up your answer and post it. Then, you can accept it. This will remove it from the Unanswered Questions list.

Answer (score 1):

If your definition of "right angle" is "an angle whose measure is 90 degrees", then this is a one-line proof:

> Suppose $\alpha$ is a right angle. Then $\alpha$ is 90 degrees. Q.E.D.

There are four possibilities, in decreasing order of likelihood (IMO):

- The *definition* of right angle in your setting is ***not*** "an angle whose measure is 90 degrees".
- You misread / misunderstood the question.
- Your professor made a mistake and meant to ask something else.
- Your professor expects you to submit the trivial proof of simply quoting the definition.

If the first case is true, then you *must* go back to your book and find out what the *definition* of a right angle is (or some other relevant theorems that say "a right angle has property *_*_") before you have any chance of doing this problem.

Of course, we here at MSE might *guess* what definition you're using, but you have no guarantee that what we think the definition should be coincides with what you're using in your class.

Comment: My mistake was the first case, the definition is a right angle is supplementary to itself

Answer (score 1):

Many proofs are possible depending on how you have defined what you mean by a right angle and a degree. A degree is perhaps best defined as an angle such that 360 adjacent lead to exactly one full rotation. It should not be too hard to go from a right angle defined by the intersection of perpendicular lines or the bisection of a straight angle to 90 degrees given that.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps equate "right angle" to "the two equal angles created from bisecting a straight angle".

180 / 2 --> 90

Your question begs for a formal proof, but presents the term "right angle" in an axiomatic manner.  As soon as you say what is special about a right angle, a proof becomes possible.